# How to build Type2Int from Int2Type?

Tags: c++, templates

I have Int2Type specialization

```
struct A; 
struct B;
template<int i> Int2Type;
template<> Int2Type<1> { typedef A type; }; 
template<> Int2Type<2> { typedef B type; };
```

Can I build reverse Type2Int specialization automatically? `Type2Int<A>::value==1` and so on

Thank you

PS Of course, I can define macro

```
#define I2T(i, T) template<> Int2Type<i> { typedef T type; }; template<> Type2Int<T> { static const int value = i; };
```

but I don't want change existing code, may be exists some other way...

**update**

A, B and others lives in different files

```
common.h
template<int i> Int2Type;

a.h
struct A;     
template<> Int2Type<1> { typedef A type; }; 

b.h
struct B;    
template<> Int2Type<2> { typedef B type; };
```

I need two compile-time "maps" - type by int and int by type;

```
Int2Type<1>::type a;
someFunc(Type2Int<A>::value)
```

Answer (score 2):

Directly? No. Such a thing would be impossible in C++. But, with an intermediate type, we could implement such a thing ourselves with a few helpers.

Without C++11, check out the [Boost.MPL](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/mpl/doc/refmanual.html) library. Specifically, we want [`boost::mpl::vector`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/mpl/doc/refmanual/vector.html):

```
typedef boost::mpl::vector<A, B> IndexedTypes;

template <int I>
struct Int2Type {
    typedef typename boost::mpl::at<IndexedTypes, 
                 boost::mpl::int_<I - 1>
                 >::type type;
};

template <typename T>
struct Type2Int {
    typedef typename boost::mpl::begin<IndexedTypes>::type begin;
    typedef typename boost::mpl::find<IndexedTypes, T>::type iter;

    static const int value = boost::mpl::distance<begin, iter>::type::value + 1;
};
```

That should give you `Int2Type<1>::type` as `A`, and `Type2Int<B>` as `2`.

With C++11, we can write these as short metafunctions based on a variadic sequence:

```
template <typename...> struct sequence { };
using IndexedTypes = sequence<A, B>;
```

Answer (score 0):

can you re-arrange your code to be more like this?

```
struct A; 
struct B;
template<int I, class Type> 
struct Int2Type
{
    static const int value = I;
    typedef Type type;
};

using type1 = Int2Type<1, A>;
using type2 = Int2Type<2, B>;
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
#include <iostream>

int getNextInt()
{
   static int next = 0;
   return ++next;
}

template <typename T> struct TypeToInt
{
   static const int value;
};

template <typename T> const int TypeToInt<T>::value  = getNextInt();

struct A;
struct B;
struct C;

int main()
{
   std::cout << TypeToInt<A>::value << std::endl;
   std::cout << TypeToInt<B>::value << std::endl;
   std::cout << TypeToInt<C>::value << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
1
2
3
```

Comment: This seems... really fragile?

Comment: @Barry, It is very simple for sure. I don't see why it is fragile. I am not asserting it is not fragile, I don't see it yet.

Comment: It's just based on the ordering of instantiations of `TypeToInt<T>` - if you happen to stick another one in somewhere, or flip two by accident... you'll get all the values wrong.

Comment: @Barry `TypeToInt<A>` could be different from one run to next. It wasn't clear to me whether keeping it same from one run to next is a requirement.